# How do I set the installation directory for pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

How can I set the installation path for `pip` using `get-pip.py` to `/usr/local/bin/`? I can't find any mention in the [setup guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) or in the command line options.

To clarify I don't mean the path where pip packages are installed, but the path where pip itself is installed (it shuold be in `/usr/local/bin/pip`).

**Edit**

I do agree with many of the comments/answers that virtualenv would be a better idea in general. However it  simply isn't the best one for me at the moment since it would be too disruptive; many of our user's scripts rely on a python2.7 being magically available; this is not convenient either and should change, but we have been using python since before virtualenv was a thing.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's a much better idea to have you pip and your packages inside a local virtualenv

Comment: @frlan agreed, but I think atm it's easier for me to do the upgrade, than to teach 16+ users how to use virtualenv; I can't do a distribution upgrade and I can't upgrade the system default since it is used by `yum`

Comment: $ virtualenv . followed by bin/python is to much for you class? Installing packages globally with pip is just not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the easiest workaround I found to do this is:

1. install `easy_install`; this will go in `/usr/local/bin/` as expected; the steps for doing this are listed [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions); I personally ended up running `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python`
2. install pip with `/usr/local/bin/easy_install pip`; this will make `pip` go in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 3):

Pip itself is a Python package, and the actual pip command just runs a small Python script which then imports and runs the pip package.

You can edit locations.py to change installation directories, however, as stated above, I **highly** recommend that you do not do this.

**Pip Command**

Pip accepts a flag, '--install-option="--install-scripts"', which can be used to change the installation directory:

```
pip install somepackage --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"
```

**Source method**

On line 124 in pip/locations.py, we see the following:

```
site_packages = sysconfig.get_python_lib()
user_site = site.USER_SITE
```

You can technically edit these to change the default install path, however, using a virtual environment would be highly preferable. This is then used to find the egglink path, which then finds the dist path (code appended below, from `pip/__init__.py`).

```
def egg_link_path(dist):
    """
    Return the path for the .egg-link file if it exists, otherwise, None.

    There's 3 scenarios:
    1) not in a virtualenv
       try to find in site.USER_SITE, then site_packages
    2) in a no-global virtualenv
       try to find in site_packages
    3) in a yes-global virtualenv
       try to find in site_packages, then site.USER_SITE
       (don't look in global location)

    For #1 and #3, there could be odd cases, where there's an egg-link in 2
    locations.

    This method will just return the first one found.
    """
    sites = []
    if running_under_virtualenv():
        if virtualenv_no_global():
            sites.append(site_packages)
        else:
            sites.append(site_packages)
            if user_site:
                sites.append(user_site)
    else:
        if user_site:
            sites.append(user_site)
        sites.append(site_packages)

    for site in sites:
        egglink = os.path.join(site, dist.project_name) + '.egg-link'
        if os.path.isfile(egglink):
            return egglink


def dist_location(dist):
    """
    Get the site-packages location of this distribution. Generally
    this is dist.location, except in the case of develop-installed
    packages, where dist.location is the source code location, and we
    want to know where the egg-link file is.

    """
    egg_link = egg_link_path(dist)
    if egg_link:
        return egg_link
    return dist.location
```

However, once again, using a virtualenv is much more traceable, and any Pip updates will **override** these changes, unlike your own virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I do agree that a virtualenv is a better option in general,  it  simply isn't the best one for me at the moment since it would be too disruptive; many of our user's scripts rely on a python2.7 being magically available, this is not convenient either, but we have been using python since before virtualenv was a thing

Comment: I added one more option, which I actually found just by doing `pip install --help`.

Comment: Wait, is this for the installation path of pip itself?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, it was poorly phrased. Added a clarification.

Comment: The simplest solution is to change the small loading script or change your path. If you are on a Unix-like system, just move it.